# When testing two contrasts on the same model over multiple sets, how many times do you adjust for multiple comparisons?

Tags: multiple-comparisons, contrasts

I have not found an answer to this specific question elsewhere.

I have a simple model with a single factor of three levels. I am running this model over about 1800 different sets. I am interested in looking at two specific contrasts across all of the sets. Would I (A) correct for multiple comparisons at both the contrast stage (e.g., Bonferroni) and at the final 1800 p-value stage (e.g., FDR) or (B) just at the final stage?
Scheffe's is excessive for my application, and I want more power than Tukey's if I can have it.

IN R:

(A) `contrast(emmeans(model, ~DV), adjust="bonferroni)` ---> `p.adjust("ADJ p's", method="fdr")`

(B) no adjust in the contrast function ---> `p.adjust("UNADJ p's", method="fdr")`

Comment: There are _ad hoc_ schemes with greater power than Scheffe that anticipate only a pre-chosen orthogonal set of contrasts.

Comment: I don't think A makes any sense. B would apply the FDR adjustment to the set of all tests, which is sensible at least.